# Geb : execute common code just before cleanup of every test case

Tags: selenium, groovy, spock, geb

We have a common screenshot capturing feature for every failed test cases which is implemented using AbstractRunListner like below:

```
public class FailureListener extends AbstarctRunLister {
....
   @Overrides
   public void error(ErrorInfo errorInfo){
       ...
       //Logic to capture screenshots
   }
}
```

This works perfectly when the test case doesn't have the cleanup block or cleanup method.

But we have used the cleanup block which will refresh or close any screen in case of failure to make the application in test ready for the next test execution. Herewith cleanup block screenshot not capturing correct screen where test case failed instead it's capture screen once cleanup execute which would have closed that screen on which failure occurred.

```
def 'do some operation on screen'(){
   given:
       //Go to that screen
   when:
       //perform some operation
   then:
       //assert the action
    cleanup:
       //close any unwanted screen to make the application ready for the next test execution
}
```

So what we can do to fix this? As I have tried multiple methods from AbstractRunListener but none of them helps as those are either executed before the test case or execute after the cleanup but here we required a method or way which can execute the logic just before cleanup but after then block executed.

Comment: Why do you close screens ready for the next test in a `cleanup` block?  Isn't that a `setup` job?  Not sure why you need to close screens at all... 

Comment: Can you please explain why (a) you are taking screenshots manually upon failure instead of extending `GebReportingSpec`, which does it automatically and why (b) you scatter `cleanup:` blocks across all feature methods instead of simply defining a `cleanup()` method in a base class in order to do anything in addition to what `GebReportingSpec` does for you already?

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I know about the cleanup() method but we have test specific configuration that we want to reset once test execution finish, so I have added a cleanup block.

Comment: GebReportingSpec also executes after cleanup block/method execute, we want to take a screenshot of the actual failure screen before cleanup block/method execute o change the screen.

Comment: There is no way to hook into something that executes before the `cleanup` block, so you'll have to take the screenshot manually in the `cleanup` block.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve what you are after if you used a `IMethodInterceptor` and registered it for all iterations in all specs in an global extension (`IGlobalExtension`) rather than a `IRunListener`. Your interceptor would wrap a call to `IMethodInvocation.proceed()` in a try/catch and do the error reporting if an exception was thrown plus rethrow the caught exception. For registering the interceptor on all iterations you might want to see

- `SpecInfo.getAllFeatures()`
- `FeatureInfo.addIterationInterceptor()`

Comment: Hi @erdi, Thanks for your answer. I have tried your solution but that also not working:
` 
public class GlobalSpecExtension extends AbstractGlobalExtension{
 public void visitSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
  spec.getAllFeatures().forEach({ feature -> feature.addIterationInterceptor(new IMethodInterceptor() {
   void intercept(IMethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    try{
     invocation.proceed()
    } catch(Throwable te){
     //Logic to capture screenshot
     throw te;
    }
   }
  }) });
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

@erdi's answer is the best solution but as a workaround you can wrap your cleanup statements in a closure and then call that closure in the spec level cleanup method. For example:

```
class SampleSpec extends YourBaseSpec {
    
    Closure cleanup

    def cleanup() {
      cleanup?.call()
    }

    def "testing cleanup"() {
      [blocks...]

      cleanup:
      cleanup = { statements like refresh(), etc }  
    }
}
```

I believe this will produce the results you want, where the the reporting spec will take the screenshot prior to the execution of the cleanup methods that refresh the page and cause whatever the failure cause was to be hidden/cleared